# Is it possible to update several objects in OpenStack Swift atomically?

Tags: openstack

We are going to evaluate a possibility of using OpenStack Swift as a storage for several TBs of user-generated content. Our users are mostly e-commerce sites and we have a business need to update all objects related to a particular e-commerce site at once.
It looks like there is an API call to create a number of objects at once but we were unable to find anything relevant to bulk update. Is it still possible to perform atomic group updates in Swift somehow?

Comment: Can you link to the API call to create multiple items at once?